# how to slice and create multiple pandas dataframes from a singe dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am reading an excel file using pandas. I want to create multiple data frames from the original data frame. each data frame name should be the row 1 heading. Also, how to skip the one column between each transaction.

Expected result:

```
transaction_1:
name id available capacity completed all

transaction_2:
name id available capacity completed all

transaction_3:
name id available capacity completed all
```

What I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import pprint as pp
pd.options.display.width = 0
pd.options.display.max_columns = 999
pd.options.display.max_rows = 999
df = pd.read_excel(r'capacity.xlsx', sheet_name='Sprint Details', header=0)
df1 = df.iloc[:, 0:3]
print(df1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this (works with `pd.__version__ == 1.1.1`):

```
df = (pd.read_excel(
          "capacity.xlsx", sheet_name="Sprint Details", header=[0, 1], index_col=[0, 1]
       )
      .dropna(axis=1, how="all")
      .rename_axis(index=["name", "id"], columns=[None, None]))

transaction_1 = df["transaction_1"].reset_index()
transaction_2 = df["transaction_2"].reset_index()
transaction_3 = df["transaction_3"].reset_index()
```

Essentially, we need to read the sheet in as a dataframe with a MultiIndex. The first 2 rows are our column names `header=[0,1]`. Whereas the first 2 columns are our index that will be used for each "subtable" `index_col=[0,1]`.

Because there are spaces in each table, we will have columns that are entirely `NaN` so we drop those with `.dropna(axis=1, how="all")`.

Because pandas does not expect the index names and columns to be in the same row, it should incorrectly parse your index column names `["name", "id"]` as the name of the second level of the column `index`. To remedy this, we can manually assign the correct index name, while also removing the column index names via `rename_axis(index=["name", "id"], columns=[None, None])`

Now that we have a nicely formatted table with a `MultiIndex` column, we can simply slice out each table, and call `.reset_index()` on each to ensure that each table has the `"name"` and `"id"` as a column in each table.

---

Edit: Seems we have a parsing difference between our versions of pandas.

**Option 1.**
If you can directly modify the excel sheet to include another row (to better separate the columns from the index names). This will provide the most robust results.
[image]

The following code works:

```
df = (pd.read_excel(
          "capacity.xlsx", sheet_name="Sprint Details", header=[0, 1], index_col=[0, 1]
       )
      .dropna(axis=1, how="all"))

transaction_1 = df["transaction_1"].reset_index()
transaction_2 = df["transaction_2"].reset_index()
transaction_3 = df["transaction_3"].reset_index()
```

---

**Option 2**

If you  can not modify the excel file, we'll need a more roundabout method unfortunately.

```
df = pd.read_excel("capacity.xlsx", header=[0,1]).dropna(axis=1, how="all")
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df.iloc[:, :2].droplevel(0, axis=1))

df = df.iloc[:, 2:].set_axis(index)

transaction_1 = df["transaction_1"].reset_index()
transaction_2 = df["transaction_2"].reset_index()
transaction_3 = df["transaction_3"].reset_index()
```

Comment: thanks @Cameron Riddell. I am getting this error after I implemented your code raise ValueError(f"Length of new names must be 1, got {len(values)}")
ValueError: Length of new names must be 1, got 2

Comment: To double check: are you sure you have `header=[0,1]` and `index_col=[0,1]` in your code when reading the excel file? The error is complaining that either your index or column only has 1 levels and the `rename_axis` function is providing input assuming there are 2 levels. You can try commenting out the `rename_axis` portion of the code and looking at the output of `df.columns` and `df.index` to ensure that you have 2 `pd.MultiIndex` objects.

Comment: yep. it's the same. ok let me try commenting out and seeing

Comment: So, even with deleting the `.rename_axis(...)` method you're still receiving an error stating `ValueError: Length of new names must be 1, got 2`?

Comment: yes. df = (pd.read_excel(
    "capacity.xlsx", sheet_name="Sprint Details", header=[0, 1], index_col=[0, 1]
))
# .dropna(axis=1, how="all"))
# .rename_axis(index=["name", "id"], columns=[None, None]))

print(df.columns)

Comment: Just updated the answer with some potential work arounds. It seems like we're working with different versions of pandas and is parsing the `MultiIndex` differently (yours leads to an error, and mine leads to a result that I overwrite)